# Dropdownlistfor selected text and value ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three dropdownlistfor in edit mode, i am able to populate the correct text in DDLFor but the id of it is coming up as 0 on submit, but if i select a different team it is coming up with correct id. Following is my code

ViewModel

```
public List<SelectListItem> TeamOneList { get; set; }
public string SelectedTeamOne { get; set; }
.... //remaining properties for DDL's..........
```

Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> TeamOneList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in db.Teams)
{
    TeamOneList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.TeamName, Value = item.TeamId.ToString() });
}
string SelectedTeamOne = db.Teams.Where(o => o.TeamId == fixture.TeamOneId).Select(s => s.TeamName).Single();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamOneId, Model.TeamOneList, Model.SelectedTeamOne, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` is the label (`null` option). It needs to be something like `"-Please select-"` (not `Model.SelectedTeamOne`)

Comment: Secondly your binding to the `TeamName` property but the option values are for the `TeamId` property. It needs to be `.Select(s => s.TeamId)` (and since `TeamId` appears to be `int` then `SelectedTeamOne` should also be `int` , not `string`

Comment: In edit mode i need to populate whatever is listed Stephen

Comment: I'll add an answer explaining all the issues

Comment: If i implement the second point i am getting the correct PK displayed in DDLFor instead of text

Answer (score 1):

Your generating the option `value` attribute based on the `TeamId` property of `Team`, but your setting the `SelectedTeamOne` value based on the `TeamName` name property, so the value of `SelectedTeamOne` does not match any of the options, therefore the first option (the `null` label option) is selected (because something has to be).

But you generating the `null` label option with the same text as `SelectedTeamOne` so it appears your are selecting it when in fact your only selecting the option with a `null` value (there is actually a second option with the same name in your dropdownlist).

Your need to change the code in the view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTeamOne, Model.TeamOneList, "-Please select-", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and then change the controller code to

```
SelectedTeamOne = db.Teams.Where(o => o.TeamId == fixture.TeamOneId).Select(s => s.TeamId).Single();
```

Note that it appears `TeamId` is typeof `int`, therefore your `SelectedTeamOne` property should also be `int`, not `string`

```
public int SelectedTeamOne { get; set; }
```

In addition, you can simply use

```
var model = new yourModelName
{
    TeamOneList = db.Teams.Select(x => new SelectListItem>
    {
        Value = x.TeamId.ToString(),
        Text = x.TeamName
    }),
    SelectedTeamOne = fixture.TeamOneId // no need to make a database call
};
return View(model);
```

or, even simpler

```
var model = new yourModelName
{
    TeamOneList = new Selectist(db.Teams, "TeamId", "TeamName"),
    SelectedTeamOne = fixture.TeamOneId // no need to make a database call
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, instead of "-Please Select-" option how can i show the actual value in DDLFor for the user to decide whether he wants to change that value by selecting the available options in DDLFor

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If (say) the value of `fixture.TeamOneId` is `5` then `SelectedTeamOne` will also be 5` and if you have a row in `Teams` with `TeamId = 5` then that option will be selected when you generate the view. If you do not want the `null` label option, then use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamOneId, Model.TeamOneList, new { @class = "form-control" })` which will not generate the label option.

Comment: But its not really clear why you have `SelectedTeamOne = db.Teams.Where(o => o.TeamId == fixture.TeamOneId).Select(s => s.TeamId).Single();` - You can just use `SelectedTeamOne = `fixture.TeamOneId` instead of making a pointless extra database call (and I will edit the answer as such)

Comment: In edit mode the user can change teams which are available in dropdownlistfor control, the reason i am using SelectedTeamOne is to show the team name in the dropdownlistfor instead of showing the user PK of that team. Teams are stored in a different table not in fixtures table. Hope i answered your queries

Comment: Sorry, your not making any sense. Your need to bind to the `TeamId` property, not the `TeamName` property (the `TeamName` is what yor display, NOT what you bind to). And `SelectedTeamOne = fixture.TeamOneId` is IDENTICAL to `db.Teams.Where(o => o.TeamId == fixture.TeamOneId).Select(s => s.TeamOneId).Single();`

Comment: This is how i made it to work as expected, "var editFixture = new FixtureViewModel {
                TeamOneId = fixture.TeamOneId, 
                TeamTwoId = fixture.TeamTwoId,

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamOneId, Model.TeamOneList, new { @class = "form-control" })" I was not passing TeamOneId, TeamTwoId before in Edit controller so when i did it is working as expected. Got rid of SelectedTeamOne altogether both in the controller and in the view. Thanks for your help Stephen

Comment: Yes, That exactly what my answer is  :)